# how to updata listview click item in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

hi any one have idea to updata listview item when listview custom listview.i am doing as follow.

```
    View v = list.getChildAt(index - list.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    TextView someText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.counttxt);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(data.get(index).get("Count"));
    i++;
    someText.setText(Integer.toString(i) + " count");
```

listview item click i need to increace count and like and unlike option for  listview item this aslo need to update.In above code textview getting null value.if any have idea please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `adapter.notifydatasetChanged();`
Just add that new row data to your `array` from which you are creating your `List` and call

```
adapter.notifydatasetChanged();
```

it will create a new `List` with the added data